# package javax.servlet.jsp.tagext does not exist

Tags: java, maven, jsp

I use Maven for including servlet-api

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And other packages seem to work perfectly fine (e.g. javax.servlet.http.*)
But when it comes to javax.servlet.jsp.tagext compiler does not see it. Application is deployed on Tomcat 9.0.55.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `javax.servlet.jsp-api` to your project. This contains the required package.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It also include the dependency to `javax.servlet-api`, so you do not need it explizitly in your project.

Comment: Thanks! Adding javax.servlet.jsp-api dependency resolved the issue, but i still need to keep javax.servlet-api dependency for some reason. Otherwise, jsp becomes the only package compiler sees in javax.servlet