Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator in my Java Web Application project
I'm working on a Java web application and I'm encountering the following exception when I try to deploy my project:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]

Here are the details of my setup:

Java version: javac 17.0.10
Web server/container: Apache Tomcat 9.0.36
Build tool: Maven

Before posting the question I have done my research and found these dependencies to be added however they are not working for me somehow
Pom.xml file
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:
Verified that the dependency is downloaded and present in the local repository.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists.
Questions:

What could be causing this NoClassDefFoundError for
TagLibraryValidator? Are there any additional dependencies I need to
include for JSP tag library validation?
Could this be related to the
version of the servlet API or a missing JAR in the classpath?
How
can I resolve this issue to successfully run and test my web application?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You shouldn't have javax and jakarta together normally. You should probably purge the former as it's superseded. That might mean changing your imports

You're basically blindly throwing different JSTL versions JSTL 1.2, JSTL 2.0 and JSTL 3.0 together into a single project. Only one of them is correct and the rest must be removed to avoid conflicts/incompatibility. The abovelinked duplicate explains in detail which version exactly is the correct one.

Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404988/package-javax-servlet-jsp-tagext-does-not-exist

@Alex: Nope. That's already provided by the server and doesn't need to be added to pom.xml at all in a properly configured Spring Boot app. The OP was just incorrectly including incompatible JSTL versions which in turn transitively included incompatible JSP API dependencies. See abovelinked duplicate for the correct answer. The explicitly declared Servlet API dependency is even unneccessary in a properly configured Spring Boot app. Less is more.

   <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>```

worked for me
